# Why I cannot increment an 'IntegerProperty' with 'int' in this case? (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm trying to modify the code of naive bayes classifier provided by the excellent book Programming Collective Intelligence, adapting it to the GAE datastore (the provided code uses pysqlite2). But trying to do it, I'm encountering in this line:

```
update.count = count + 1
```

from this block:

```
def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      fc_value = fc(feature = f, category = cat, count = 1)
      fc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM fc where feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
#      self.con.execute(
 #       "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
  #      % (count+1,f,cat))
```

This error:

```
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 221, in post
    sampletrain(nb)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 206, in sampletrain
    cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 144, in train
    self.incf(f,cat)
  File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 82, in incf
    update.count = count + 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'IntegerProperty' and 'int'
```

And I can not understand: why I cannot increment `count` with 1?

Why `update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM cc where category =:category", category = cat).get() 
        update.count = count + 1` is an 'IntegerProperty' and not an integer?

How can I fix? What is the correct syntax to do this `update.count = count + 1` operation?

Here the entire code:

```
import os

import random

import re

import math

from google.appengine.ext import db

import webapp2

import jinja2

from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(autoescape=True,
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')))

class fc(db.Model):
    feature = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()

class cc(db.Model):
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()

def getfeatures(doc):
  splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
  # Split the words by non-alpha characters
  words=[s.lower() for s in splitter.split(doc)
          if len(s)>2 and len(s)<20]
  return dict([(w,1) for w in words])

class classifier:
  def __init__(self,getfeatures, filename=None):
    # Counts of feature/category combinations
    self.fc={}
    # Counts of documents in each category
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures

#  def setdb(self,dbfile):
#    self.con=sqlite.connect('db_file')
#    self.con=sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
#    self.con.execute('create table if not exists fc(feature,category,count)')
#    self.con.execute('create table if not exists cc(category,count)')

  def incf(self,f,cat):
    count=self.fcount(f,cat)
    if count==0:
      fc_value = fc(feature = f, category = cat, count = 1)
      fc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM fc where feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
#      self.con.execute(
 #       "update fc set count=%d where feature='%s' and category='%s'"
  #      % (count+1,f,cat))

  def fcount(self,f,cat):
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM fc WHERE feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
    logging.debug('This is a log message.')
#    res=self.con.execute(
#      'select count from fc where feature="%s" and category="%s"'
#      %(f,cat)).fetchone()
    if res is None: return 0
    else:
        res = fc.count
        return res
#        return float(res[0])

  def incc(self,cat):
    count=self.catcount(cat)
    if count==0:
      #  self.con.execute("insert into cc values ('%s',1)" % (cat))
      cc_value = cc(category = cat, count = 1)
      cc_value.put()
    else:
        update = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM cc where category =:category", category = cat).get()
        update.count = count + 1
        update.put()
#      self.con.execute("update cc set count=%d where category='%s'"
#                       % (count+1,cat))

  def catcount(self,cat):
#    res=self.con.execute('select count from cc where category="%s"'
 #                        %(cat)).fetchone()
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT count FROM cc WHERE category =:category", category = cat).get()
    if res is None: return 0
#    else: return float(res[0])
    else: return float(res)

  def categories(self):
#    cur = self.con.execute('select category from cc');
    cur = db.GqlQuery("SELECT category FROM cc").fetch(999)
    return [d[0] for d in cur]

  def totalcount(self):
   # res=self.con.execute('select sum(count) from cc').fetchone();
    all_cc = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM cc").fetch(999)
    res = 0
    for cc in all_cc:
        count = cc.count
        res+=count
#    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT sum(count) FROM cc").get()
#    if res==None: return 0
    if res == 0: return 0
#    return res[0]
    return res

  def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Increment the count for every feature with this category
    for f in features.keys():
##    for f in features:
      self.incf(f,cat)
    # Increment the count for this category
    self.incc(cat)
#    self.con.commit()

  def fprob(self,f,cat):
    if self.catcount(cat)==0: return 0
    # The total number of times this feature appeared in this
    # category divided by the total number of items in this category
    return self.fcount(f,cat)/self.catcount(cat)

  def weightedprob(self,f,cat,prf,weight=1.0,ap=0.5):
    # Calculate current probability
    basicprob=prf(f,cat)
    # Count the number of times this feature has appeared in
    # all categories
    totals=sum([self.fcount(f,c) for c in self.categories()])

    # Calculate the weighted average
    bp=((weight*ap)+(totals*basicprob))/(weight+totals)
    return bp

class naivebayes(classifier):
  def __init__(self,getfeatures):
    classifier.__init__(self, getfeatures)
    self.thresholds={}

  def docprob(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    # Multiply the probabilities of all the features together
    p=1
    for f in features: p*=self.weightedprob(f,cat,self.fprob)
    return p

  def prob(self,item,cat):
    catprob=self.catcount(cat)/self.totalcount()
    docprob=self.docprob(item,cat)
    return docprob*catprob

  def setthreshold(self,cat,t):
    self.thresholds[cat]=t

  def getthreshold(self,cat):
    if cat not in self.thresholds: return 1.0
    return self.thresholds[cat]

  def classify(self,item,default=None):
    probs={}
    # Find the category with the highest probability
    max=0.0
    for cat in self.categories():
      probs[cat]=self.prob(item,cat)
      if probs[cat]>max:
        max=probs[cat]
        best=cat
    # Make sure the probability exceeds threshold*next best
    for cat in probs:
      if cat==best: continue
      if probs[cat]*self.getthreshold(best)>probs[best]: return default
    return best

def sampletrain(cl):
  cl.train('Nobody owns the water.','good')
  cl.train('the quick rabbit jumps fences','good')
  cl.train('buy pharmaceuticals now','bad')
  cl.train('make quick money at the online casino','bad')
  cl.train('the quick brown fox jumps','good')


class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template_values = {"given_sentence":'put a name here'}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))

    def post(self):
        nb = naivebayes(getfeatures)
        sampletrain(nb)
        given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence")
        spam_result = nb.classify(given_sentence)
        submit_button = self.request.get("submit_button")
        if submit_button:
            self.redirect('/test_result?spam_result=%s&given_sentence=%s' % (spam_result, given_sentence))

class test_resultHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        spam_result = self.request.get("spam_result")
        given_sentence = self.request.get("given_sentence")
        test_result_values = {"spam_result": spam_result,
                             "given_sentence": given_sentence}
        template = jinja_environment.get_template('test_result.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(test_result_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler), ('/test_result', test_resultHandler)],
                              debug=True)
```

Comment: What is this `self.fcount(f,cat)`

Comment: I added the entire code, @Aesthete, including the `def fcount(self,f,cat):` method. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Properties" are typically meant to be accessed on object instances, not on classes.  Try changing:

```
class fc(db.Model):
    feature = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()
```

To something like:

```
class fc_class(db.Model):
    feature = db.StringProperty()
    category = db.StringProperty()
    count = db.IntegerProperty()
fc = fc_class()
```

(Not that this is a great design, but I think it will fix the problem you're having -- namely that property objects only get special behavior when they're accessed via a class isntance, and not via the class itself.)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but now I got this:   `File "C:\Users\CG\Desktop\Google Drive\Sci&Tech\projects\naivebayes\main.py", line 97, in fcount
    res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM fc WHERE feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 296, in class_for_kind
    raise KindError('No implementation for kind \'%s\'' % kind)
KindError: No implementation for kind 'fc'` Thanks for helping!

Comment: Now I adequate other parts of code (like this: `fc_value = fc_class(feature = f, category = cat, count = 1)`) and it seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, it seems like the problem may be in the `res` assignment:

```
def fcount(self,f,cat):
  res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM fc WHERE feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
  logging.debug('This is a log message.')
  if res is None: return 0
  else:
    res = fc.count
    return res
```

From what I could tell, you are assigning an unbound method of `class fc` to `res`, which as @Hamish points out is indeed an `IntegerProperty()`. Instead (and again, not a professional here), you probably want to return a value like so:

```
def fcount(self,f,cat):
  res = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM fc WHERE feature =:feature AND category =:category", feature = f, category = cat).get()
  logging.debug('This is a log message.')
  if res is None: return 0
  else:
    return res.count
```

I believe that `res` is already a Query instance (which is what you want), and you can then pull the `count` attribute to get the value you want.